# How to kill an HttpConnection using ConnectionManager in Java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on Google Maps in Android. It requests to the server for some content to be showed on markers, now I want to kill the connection of pending requests or all requests when user pans the map.

Comment: use `HttpConnection.shutdown()`.

Comment: Why can't you simply call the HttpConnection's close method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the underlying `InputStream` this will close the connection as well.

Regaring submitting requests to something (such as to your connection) and then cancelling the requests you can check `ExecutorService` interface. It has `execute()`, `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`